# Yaw Pitch Length преобразовать в XYZ

Tags: java, математика, vector

У меня есть 3д вектор который хранит в себе Yaw, Pitch, Length...
Length - длинна линии...как можно преобразовать YPL вектор в XYZ вектор?у меня удачно удавалось конвертировать XYZ в YPL,поэтому я вполне уверен что существует и обратный процесс...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта операция, которую Вы ищите - перевод из [сферической](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82)  системы координат в [прямоугольную](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82)(декартову) систему координат. На картинке ниже так же присутствуют обозначения для цилиндрической системы координат, они отмечены синим цветом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формула для этой операции выглядит вот так:

```
X = L * sin(Pi-P) * cos(Y)
Y = L * cos(Pi-P)
Z = L * sin(Pi-P) * sin(Y)
```

Формула обратного перехода будет такая:

```
L = sqrt(X*X + Y*Y + Z*Z)
P = Pi - atan(sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)/Z)
Y = atan(Y/X)
```

PS: Если Вы посмотрите формулы на вики, там не будет вычитания из PI, это связано с тем что в сферической системе координат угол места(pitch) откладывается от оси Z а не от плоскости XY, это можно наблюдать на картинке выше.